# sort an array of arrays based on number of occurences in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I want this integer array to be sorted in the right order based on its number of occurrences.

```
question = [[1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 129, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 139], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141], [30], [77]] 

question.flatten.uniq.size = 90

answer = sort_it(question)

answer = [77, 68, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 31, 139, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 135, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 136, 66, 67, 7, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 1, 78, 79, 81, 129, 132, 133, 134, 45, 65, 32, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 33, 41, 69, 130, 137, 138, 140, 141, 30]

answer.uniq.size = 90
```

Here is my Ruby code:

```
def sort_it(actual)
        join=[]
        buffer = actual.dup 
        final = [ ]

                (actual.size-2).downto(0) {|j|
                join.unshift(actual.map{|i| i }.inject(:"&"))
                actual.pop
                }
        ordered_join =  join.reverse.flatten
        final << ordered_join
        final << buffer.flatten - ordered_join

        final.flatten
end
```

Is this approach OK? Is there a more efficient approach?

### EDIT:

*As a tribute to tokland and niklas, edited the answer which was in the wrong order before.
Thanks!*

Comment: What do you mean by "the right order based on its number of occurrences"? Can you say more explicitly what it is that you want the code to do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's it for?

Comment: I don't get it. `question` is not an integer array?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan : Now, I want to search for the set of books with the features, "fiction","hardcover","2011". I will have book_ids mapped to those features in a table and select them to form an array like [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[4,9,8]]. So, book_id 4 is what the user is looking for. I want this array to be ordered as [4,3,1,2,5,6,9,8]. When I display my results in that order, user is happy. Do i make sense?

Comment: @NiklasB: I dont get you. Question is an integer arrray.

Comment: 77 appears 3 times, should be the first in answer?

Comment: @beck: question is an array of integer arrays. Also, please include the desired output (because as tokland suggested, your `answer` doesn't make sense on first glance). In any case, from your description I think that Marc is spot-on with his answer. However, you should really solve this using a custom SQL query, your database is a *lot* faster than Ruby.

Comment: @tokland: you are right!

Comment: @NiklasB: Oh, I hadn't considered that!!!. Listen man, my database is highly normalized I would say, for example, we have tables for everything to avoid duplication. So for the example I stated, "fiction hardcover 2011", this will goto genres table, bindings table and publishing_date table and fetch book_ids put it in a ruby array and from that array i will execute Marc's function to sort it and after that, I will goto the books table, select books and order by this sorted order and show it to the users. Did i complicate anything?. Forgive my brains man, its not so good looking!

Comment: @beck03076: Why isn't it good-looking? I'd say that is perfect for a good query solving this in one rush.

Comment: @NiklasB: Oh, thanks!! but can you throw a little light on "good query solving this in one rush", i would like to know the pros of my system.

Comment: @beck: See my answer for a rough scaffold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group_by`:

```
question.flatten.group_by{|x| x}.sort_by{|k, v| -v.size}.map(&:first)
```

Comment: @NiklasB. I was going to delete my solution! You were quicker to post... and quicker to delete!

Comment: But yours is nicer, as it doesn't involve a separate hash.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with sort_by{|k, v| -v.size} calls v.size every time elements are compared. More effective solution:

```
question.flatten.group_by(&:to_i).map{|k,v| [k, -v.size]}.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first)
```

Though size of array is easy to get, it is unnecessary expense (O(sorting algorithm) instead of O(n)), and this idiom is good to remember anyway for more expensive operations