# Sort an array of arrays by the number of same occurencies in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397769/sort-an-array-of-arrays-based-on-number-of-occurences-in-ruby).

I have an array of arrays of AR items looking something like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [7,8,9], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]]
```

I would like to sort it by number of same occurences of the second array:

```
[[7,8,9], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

My real data are more complexes, looking something like:

```
  raw_data = {}
  raw_data[:grapers] = []

  suggested_data = {}
  suggested_data[:grapers] = []

  varietals = []
  similar_vintage.varietals.each do |varietal| 
    # sub_array             
    varietals << Graper.new(:name => varietal.grape.name, :grape_id => varietal.grape_id, :percent => varietal.percent) 
  end

  raw_data[:grapers] << varietals
```

So, I want to sort *raw_data[:grapers]* by the max occurrencies of each varietals array comparing this value: *grape_id* inside them.

When I need to sort a classical array of data by max occurencies I do that:

```
grapers_with_frequency = raw_data[:grapers].inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
suggested_data[:grapers] << raw_data[:grapers].max_by { |v| grapers_with_frequency[v] }
```

This code doesn't work cos there are sub arrays there, including AR models that I need to analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
array.group_by(&:itself)        # grouping
     .sort_by {|k, v| -v.size } # sorting
     .map(&:first)              # optional step, depends on your real data
#=> [[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Hello Ilya, The fact is I need to compare the value of :grape_id in the Graper model, not only a number as shown in my first example. I suppose I need to do this in .map ?

Comment: @alex.bour,  you should group by `grape_id`, then sort by values size, then map.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) for the `sort_by` method. It allows you to sort an array using anything associated with the elements, rather than the values of the elements.

```
my_array.sort_by { |elem| -my_array.count(elem) }.uniq
=> [[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

This example sorts by the count of each element in the original array. This is preceded with a minus so that the elements with the highest count are first. The `uniq` is to only have one instance of each element in the final result.

You can include anything you like in the `sort_by` block.

As Ilya has pointed out, having `my_array.count(elem)` in each iteration will be costlier than using `group_by` beforehand. This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: it is super inefficient since you need to calculate `my_array.count(elem)` each time.

Comment: That's true. I'll make a note of this.

Comment: You could shove the results in a mapping hash: `hh={}; my_array.sort_by { |elem| -(hh[elem.to_s] ||= my_array2.count(elem)) }.uniq` for caching

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [7,8,9], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |a,h| h[a] += 1 }.
    sort_by(&:last).
    reverse.
    map(&:first)
 #=> [[7.8.9]. [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (here `0`) that is the hash's default value.

Comment: or just `.sort_by { |e| -e.last }.map(&:first)`, without `reverse`

Comment: @llya, I considered that (and saw you had used that), but went with `reverse` because I thought it read slightly better. I also considered `max_by(are.size, &:last)`.